Generate non-id value from sequence
I have an entity with two fields which both use the same sequence, but when debugging I see that only the id field value is being generated:
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GenericGenerator(name="my_seq" , type = StringIdGenerator.class)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "my_seq")
    private String id;

// Some field

    @Column(name = "SOME_OTHER_ID")
    @GenericGenerator(name="my_seq" , type = StringIdGenerator.class)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "my_seq")
    private String someOtherId;
}

Is there a way to generate values for non-identifier columns? I tried using BeforeExecutionGenerator, but the result is the same. I'm using Hibernate 6.4.1.
My generator:
public class StringIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    @Override
    public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.getJdbcConnectionAccess()
                .obtainConnection()
                .prepareStatement("SELECT " + sequenceName + ".NEXTVAL as next_val FROM dual")) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    return String.valueOf(resultSet.getLong("next_val"));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IdGenerateException("Failed to generate custom ID using sequence", e);
        }
    }
}


You don't close JDBC connection. You nned another try in you generate.

As per specification:
"The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property or field of an entity or mapped superclass in conjunction with the Id annotation"
so unless you define your own annotation and annotation processor to imitate what the standard one for @Id does, GeneratedValue on a on-Id field is a no-op in most JPA implementations - but exceptions may exist.
